# Why does to [bend right] change the node placement behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (0,0) -- (1,1) node[right,midway]{\small$\alpha$};  %
\draw[<->] (1,0) to [bend right]  (2,1) node[right,midway] {\small$\alpha$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With Tikz 2.1 the output looks like this 
[image]

The second alpha is placed totally wrong just because the line is bent. This worked fine under texlive 2009 and tikz 2.00. Any Idea where this comes from ?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, do you intend to add an answer yourself (that is perfectly fine, by the way), or are you looking for more than what you wrote at the end?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Done. I just wanted to wait a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got it apparently the syntax changed:

```
\draw[<->] (1,0) to [bend right] node[right,midway] {\small$\alpha$} (2,1) ;
```

works.